# PHP sort/reorder the array by specific start on key

Tags: php, arrays

I want to sort or reorder the array element based on start on value.

My array:

```
[
    0 => 'Sun',
    1 => 'Mon',
    2 => 'Tue',
    3 => 'Wed',
    4 => 'Thu',
    5 => 'Fri',
    6 => 'Sat'
]
```

$startOn = 3;

Expected Output :

```
[
    3 => 'Wed',
    4 => 'Thu',
    5 => 'Fri',
    6 => 'Sat',
    0 => 'Sun',
    1 => 'Mon',
    2 => 'Tue',
]
```

I tried using `uksort` but it does not return the expected output.

```
uksort($weekDays, function ($a, $b) use ($startOn) {
    return $startOn-$a;
});
```

Current output :

```
[
    3 => 'Wed'
    4 => 'Thu'
    5 => 'Fri'
    6 => 'Sat'
    2 => 'Tue'
    1 => 'Mon'
    0 => 'Sun'
]
```

Comment: That's not sorting. Just slice subarray and append it to the end.

Comment: You can use `($k + 7 - $startOn) % 7` as the key in `uksort`, check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57968296/6521116)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `foreach`

```
$start = 3;
$r1 = $r2 = [];
foreach($a as $k => $v){
  ($k >= $start) ? ($r1[$k]=$v) : ($r2[$k]=$v);
}
$r = $r1 + $r2;
print_r($r);
```

Working example :- https://3v4l.org/1KDoR

Comment: Method 1 - It's ok but when $startOn = 0 that error and 
Method 2 - when $startOn = 0 that time remove the last element

Answer (score 1):

As the `array_slice()` code has been removed from the other answer, thought I would add my version here.

The main thing is to set the fourth parameter to `true` so that it retains the key...

```
$weekDays = array_slice($weekDays, $startOn, null, true) 
        + array_slice($weekDays, 0, $startOn, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

With `uksort`, check the [Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/22f3b388695e41cea365593567e1aa5cc18e117f)

```
$startOn = 3;
uksort($array,function($a,$b)use($startOn){return ($a + 7 - $startOn) % 7 - ($b + 7 - $startOn) % 7;});
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is working solution,

```
$k = array_search(3, array_keys($arr));
$arr = array_slice($arr,$k,null,true) + array_slice($arr,0,$k,true);
print_r($arr);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/H42XL).

**Output:-**

```
Array
(
    [3] => Wed
    [4] => Thu
    [5] => Fri
    [6] => Sat
    [0] => Sun
    [1] => Mon
    [2] => Tue
)
```

[array_search](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) — Searches the array for a given value and returns the first corresponding key if successful

[array_slice](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) — Extract a slice of the array

> **Note:**
>
> **array_slice()** will reorder and reset the integer array indices by
>   default. This behaviour can be changed by setting preserve_keys to
>   **TRUE**. String keys are always preserved, regardless of this parameter.